# PHP call methods of others classes

Tags: php

In my php project I've create 4 classes

CONNECTION

```
class Mysqliconn {

   public $mysqli;  

   public function __construct(){
      include "dbconfig.php";
      $this->connect($host, $user, $password, $database, $charset);
   }

   public function connect (.....)
      $this->mysqli = new mysqli(......);
   }
}
```

UPLOAD

```
class Upload {

     private $db;

     public function __construct( Mysqliconn $db ) {
        $this->db = $db; 
     }

     public function getID($id) {
        echo $id;
     }
}
```

USERS

```
class Users {

 private $db;

      public function __construct( Mysqliconn $db ) {
          $this->db = $db; 
      }

      public function getName($name) {
      echo $name;
      }
}
```

CARS

```
class Cars {

     private $db;

     public function __construct( Mysqliconn $db ) {
            $this->db = $db; 
     }

     public function getCars($cars) {
        echo $cars;
     }
 }
```

In my php page I instantiate the classes in this way

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    if(file_exists('class/class.' . strtolower($class_name) . '.php')) {
        require_once('class/class.' . strtolower($class_name) . '.php'); 
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception("Unable to load $class_name.");
    }
}

$db = new Mysqliconn();
$up = new Upload($db);
$us = new Users($db);
$cs = new Cars($db);

$cs->getCars('BMW');
$us->getName('Foo');
```

In my Cars Class I'd like to call method of classes Users and Upload. 
Is it possibile to do? How could I do this? Thanks.

Comment: You can call a public method of `Users` if you have an object of type `Users` in your `Cars` class.

Comment: Pass an instance of `Users` and `Upload` to your `Cars` class in the constructor. Store them as properties on the `Users` class and you can then access them.

Comment: You can call static functions without creating an object too. `public static function foo(){...}`

Comment: You would have to inject $up and $us instances to your $cs object. Read more about Dependency injection

Comment: You should use classes and objects with a goal, not just for the sake of using them; as it is clear you still have to go through the basics of OOP [at least from you getters definitions...], I strongly advise you to read about such topic, and then to come back to shape you program with the new knowledge.

Comment: I strongly recommend you read this book.  http://www.martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call a public static function inside an other class:

```
class Users {

private $db;

  public function __construct( Mysqliconn $db ) {
      $this->db = $db; 
  }

  public static function getName($name) {
  echo $name;
  }
}


class Cars {
 private $db;

 public function __construct( Mysqliconn $db ) {
        $this->db = $db; 
 }

 public function getCars($cars) {
    echo $cars;
 }

    public function callGetName($name)
   {
         return  Users:: getName($name) ;
   }
}
```

Another option would be:

```
function callGetName($name)
 {
   $user = new Users();
   $user->getName($name);
 }
```

Comment: For your example the `getName` function on the `Users` class must be made static.

Comment: Thanks! It works if I define static function. But with public function isn't possibile to do?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see that it was a question. I'll search. Anyway, the function can still be public.

Comment: Added a new option where you can use public functions.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Example{

    public function __construct(){
        $otherClass = new OtherClass();
        $otherClass->functionInOtherClass();
    }

}
```

or

```
class Example{

    public function __construct($objFromOtherClass){
        $objFromOtherClass->functionInOtherClass();
    }

}
```

or

```
class Example{

    public function __construct(OtherClass $objFromOtherClass){
        $objFromOtherClass->functionInOtherClass();
    }

}
```

If the object in question will be used throughout your `Example` class:

```
class Example{

    protected $objFromOtherClass;

    public function __construct(OtherClass $objFromOtherClass){
        $this->objFromOtherClass = $objFromOtherClass;
    }

    public function test(){
        $this->objFromOtherClass->functionInOtherClass();
    }

}
```

Comment: The third option (type hinted object passed during construction) is the best one. This will provide warnings when doing silly things (like passing the wrong type) as well as provide a way to easily replace the real `OtherClass` with a mock during testing.

Comment: @Mike Something I wish PHP enforced :/

Comment: And how can I istantiate my cars class? $cs = new Cars($db , $us, $up)? thanks